# UTF8 combination PHP/MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

My sql database have utf8_unicode_ci collation and HTML have utf8 (meta charset="utf-8").

when i write in PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `subjects` WHERE  `year` = '$year'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='" .  $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
```

instead čćšđ i am getting some crazy values like: ?�...

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

before

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `subjects` WHERE  `year` = '$year'";
```

Comment: So it's 2 more queries... Use them only once, then delete...

Comment: @PauliusMarčiukaitis after the `mysql connection` place the queries will work as a GLOBAL to mysql

Answer (score 3):

Encode your HTML or PHP file to UTF-8. Possible with most editors. What is more about your code, if you want to make it with less code use (I think you need only ASSOC values)

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

instead of

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: +vote for pointing this `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` out